# Laravel use Request validation with api

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to implement validation in my api like this:

```
public function store(RideUpdateRequest $request)
    {
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

        $ride = Ride::create([
            'user_id'       => $user->id,
            'time'          => $request->time,
            'date'          => $request->date,
            'type_id'       => $request->type_id,
            'location_id'   => $request->location_id,
            'billabletime'  => $request->billabletime
        ]);

        $ride->save();

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Rit succesvol aangemaakt.'], 200);
    }
```

**RideUpdateRequest:**

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'time'             =>  'required|integer',
            'date'             =>  'required|date',
            'type_id'          =>  'required|integer',
            'location_id'      =>  'required|integer',
            'billabletime'     =>  'required|integer'
        ];
    }
```

So how could I give a error message back in json (if the request validation fails)? Right now in postman I receive nothing back?

--EDIT--

response:

```
{
  "billabletime": [
    "The billabletime field is required."
  ]
}
```

Could I get something like this?:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "The billabletime field is required."
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you take a look at the **FormRequest** class, you'll see a `response()` method defined as something like:

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    if ($this->expectsJson()) {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }
    ...
}
```

So you can either set an `Accept: aplication/json` request header to comply with the `expectsJson` condition, or force the default response behavior by sepcifying the `response()` method in your own **RideUpdateRequest** class:

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    // Always return JSON.
    return response()->json($errors, 422);
}
```

Comment: thanks! One more question right now I receive it not like an object. Is that possible? See my edit for what I mean. Thankyou

Comment: You can try this: `return response()->json(['error' => $errors], 400);`

Answer (score 7):

In laravel 8 you can control the response by overriding the failedValidation function in your FormRequest class:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
{
    $response = new Response(['error' => $validator->errors()->first()], 422);
    throw new ValidationException($validator, $response);
}
```

Comment: I am checking how Laravel 8 handle with api validation, thanks for the tips

Comment: Another tip is when u send API request, the header need to add `accept:application/json`, then it will automatic to return json.

Answer (score 1):

> response:
>
> ```
> {
>   "billabletime": [
>     "The billabletime field is required."
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> Could I get something like this?:
>
> ```
> {
>   "error": {
>     "The billabletime field is required."
>   }
> }
> ```

Laravel uses this format because a) there may be multiple fields that fail validation and b) there may be multiple failures for a particular field.

For example:

```
{
  "email": [
    "The email field is invalid."
  ],
  "password": [
    "The password field must contain a number.",
    "The password field must contain a special character."
  ]
}
```

Your `"error": { ... }` is also unnecessary, because Laravel's validation system sends a `422 Unprocessable Entity` status code with the response.

Comment: Oke I understand that. But in my angular app It's very difficult to use that format.

Comment: @Jamie Then you'll need to decide which of the multiple errors get sent back.